# Assert for the existence of a specific S3 bucket with a CDK autogenerated name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

Imagine a toy CDK stack with one S3 bucket:

```js
    import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
    import * as s3 from '@aws-cdk/aws-s3';
    
    export class BucketStack extends cdk.Stack {
     constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
       super(scope, id, props);
    
       new s3.Bucket(this, 'MySpecificBucket');
     }
    }
```

Importantly, we have specified only the `id` of the resource and not its name (i.e., `BucketName`). It's good practice not to rely on a specific name since they have to be unique, so even the CDK docs recommend letting CDK [autogenerate the name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3.Bucket.html#bucketname). This is perfectly fine - but how do you now test for the existence of this specific bucket in a Jest test case?

For instance, if we had:

```js
    import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
    import { Template } from 'aws-cdk-lib/assertions';
    import { BucketStack  } from '../lib/bucket-stack';
    
    let template: Template;
    
    beforeAll(async () => {
        const app = new cdk.App();
        // WHEN
        const stack = new BucketStack(app, 'MyTestStack', {});
        // THEN
        template = Template.fromStack(stack);
    });
    
    describe("My test suite", () => {
        test("S3 bucket exists", () => {
            template.hasResourceProperties("AWS::S3::Bucket", {
                BucketName: "wont-work" // this is autogenerated!
            });
        });
    });
```

The template will have something like:

```js
    {
       MySpecificBucketF68F3FF0: {
         Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket',
         UpdateReplacePolicy: 'Retain',
         DeletionPolicy: 'Retain'
       }
    }
```

A potential solution could check using a regex for "MySpecificBucket*" to exists, but I guess there are no guarantees what kind of a name CDK will autogenerate. Also, it's not satisfactory to just count the number of S3 buckets via `resourceCountIs` because I want to assert the existence of a specific bucket whose name I specifically don't care about. If I just have the `id` specified, how can I write a test with these requirements (or should I somehow change my thinking)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are several options to assert the presence of a resource with a specific ID.

Assert with [escape hatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html) syntax:

```js
const bucket = stack.node.tryFindChild("MySpecificBucket");

expect(bucket).toBeDefined();
expect(bucket instanceof s3.Bucket).toBe(true);
expect(bucket?.node.defaultChild instanceof s3.CfnBucket).toBe(true);
```

Assert with the CDK testing construct and regex:

```js
expect(
  Object.keys(template.findResources("AWS::S3::Bucket")).find((key) =>
    key.match(/^MySpecificBucket[A-F0-9]{8}$/)
  )
).toBeDefined();
```

If you have many such assertions to make, consider snapshot testing.  This is what the CDK itself does.  See the [@aws-cdk/integ-tests-alpha](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/integ-tests-alpha-readme.html) module.

Comment: For the last example, is there a guarantee CDK will autogenerate a name that matches that regex? By looking at examples it seems to work like that currently, but is it promised to behave like that always?

Comment: @Juho I have seen no such documented guarantee.  Nevertheless, because any CloudFormation logical ID change causes resource replacement, all CDK stacks ever created implicitly rely on the CDK not changing the naming logic.  So I think you are safe assuming ID stability.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, they also intentionally write a test that fails, grab the correct identifier from the output, and fix the test in the [CDK TypeScript workshop](https://cdkworkshop.com/20-typescript/70-advanced-topics/100-construct-testing/1000-assertion-test.html).

Specifically, they do:

```
$ npm run test

> cdk-workshop@0.1.0 test /home/aws-cdk-intro-workshop
> jest

 FAIL  test/hitcounter.test.ts
  ✓ DynamoDB Table Created (184ms)
  ✕ Lambda Has Environment Variables (53ms)

  ● Lambda Has Environment Variables

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  - 2
    + Received  + 2

      Object {
        "Variables": Object {
          "DOWNSTREAM_FUNCTION_NAME": Object {
    -       "Ref": "TestFunctionXXXXX",
    +       "Ref": "TestFunction22AD90FC",
          },
          "HITS_TABLE_NAME": Object {
    -       "Ref": "MyTestConstructHitsXXXXX",
    +       "Ref": "MyTestConstructHits24A357F0",
          },
        },
      }

      37 |     Environment: envCapture,
      38 |   });
    > 39 |   expect(envCapture.asObject()).toEqual(
         |                                 ^
      40 |     {
      41 |       Variables: {
      42 |         DOWNSTREAM_FUNCTION_NAME: {

      at Object.<anonymous> (test/hitcounter.test.ts:39:33)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.971 s, estimated 4 s
Ran all test suites.
```

I suppose they wouldn't advocate for this approach if there was a better alternative.